# Anime or manga about a dude who is kicked out of his family for being weak, makes a contract with a demon and meets a vampire

Tags: story-identification, anime, manga

It starts with the MC (a dude) getting kicked out of his family for being too weak, he has like 2 ish brothers.  I remember there was one brother who didn't completely hate him and had short brown hair.

At some point in the story he makes a demon contract with Asura or something and meets a vampire? who I think was tasked to kill him and also has a demon contract.  There was something special about his bloodline (family) that allows them to be a disciple of a god while still retaining their other powers I think?

He was the disciple of the sword god who had a Japanese name and this god was trying to kill the other gods, but he ended up dying eventually.  The sword god was the 2nd oldest god and the oldest god (who killed him) was all white like the one in *Mushoku Tensei*.

Comment: Sounds a bit like Kaze no Stigma.

Answer (score 2):

Some details are off, but I am most certain you are talking about "The Great Mage Returns After 4000 Years".

Frey Blake's brother really cared about him and was actually relieved when Frey got kicked out of the family. Because he won't have to suffer being in this vile family.
Frey died and his body became possessed by the greatest magician, who at the time was locked up by demigods.
The mc indeed has a connection with Asura and can summon him through magic circle.
And he does meet a vampire, who becomes his ally.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Could you [edit] in some details as to why you think this is what the OP is looking for? Matching details in the question, or a synopsis would help. Please see [answer] for some more info